# Provide Flux to signal events without a concrete value?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

How can I setup a stream/publisher with project [Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) that emits events over time but without any concrete values. I thought about `Flux<Void>` but the [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/) mentions that `Flux<Void>` is an empty stream.

For example I consume a stream with filesystem changes `Flux<Path>`. I do not need the `Path` value but want to add another events. In order to do this I have to create dummy `Path` objects.

```java
Flux<Path> events = getFilesystemChanges();
events.startWith(Path.of("dummy"))
      .map(e -> 42 /* subsequent operator ignores the emitted value */)
      ...
```

Is it possible to avoid the dummy values or is there maybe a convention to express that the values aren't read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactive streams only work with objects (you can never stream `null`), and since `Void` can never be instantiated you can therefore never send any values - just a completion signal.

I'm not quite sure of the use case here, but there's two different approaches you can take that spring to mind:

- If you never need the value, you can just map to an `Object`, i.e.

  ```
  Flux<Object> events = getFilesystemChanges().map(p -> new Object());
  ```

  You can then just use `events.startWith(new Object())` and carry on. (You can pick a more appropriate type than `Object` if you want of course, or create your own.)
- If you need the actual values emitted, but sometimes need to just interject your own "dummy" values, then you can have a stream of `Optional<Path>` instead:

  ```
  Flux<Optional<Path>> events = getFilesystemChanges().map(Optional::of);
  ```

  Then you can do `events.startWith(Optional.empty())` to prepend a "dummy" path to the stream.

FWIW, the second approach I've often used for "heartbeat" type functions, where I want a stream of values to be emitted, but also want to ensure there's activity once every (timeperiod) to keep an underlying connection alive. The latter is where I'll often use empty optionals.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but have you tried Flux.just(Optional.empty())?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30870244)